# Mean of passwords to be checked before guessing right, from a file with $x$ passwords

Tags: probability

Given a passwords space of size $N$, **with uniform distribution**, and a file with $x$ passwords, I want to calculate the mean of **number of passwords to be checked until it matches at least one of the $x$ passwords**.
So, we take one password, try to match it with all of the $x$ passwords in file, take another one and so on, until we succeed.

I've got to this sum:
$$1\cdot\frac{x}{N}+2\cdot(\frac{N-1}{N})^{x}\cdot\frac{x}{N-1}+3\cdot(\frac{N-1}{N})^{x}\cdot(\frac{N-2}{N-1})^{x}\cdot\frac{x}{N-2}+...$$

Which can be written like:
$$\sum\limits _{i=0}^{N-1}(i+1)\cdot(\frac{N-i}{N})^{x}\cdot\frac{x}{N-i}$$

But I can't really solve it. I also tried using the tail sum formula, but it got me to the next sum:
$$\sum\limits _{i=0}^{N-1}(\frac{N-i}{N})^{x}=\frac{1}{N^{x}}\sum\limits _{i=0}^{N-1}(N-i)^{x}$$

Which also isn't trivial.

Comment: What about the "alphabet" size from which a password is created ?

Comment: @trueblueanil: I don't think that matters as we know the size of the password space, A larger "alphabet" would just mean shorter passwords to achieve the given size of the space. I don't believe it to be of any importance (it might directly harm the thinking) that it's passwords, the question is something like: What is the mean number of guesses when there's $x$ good passwords, and they come from a uniform distribution.